# Find position of first 1 in unsorted array?

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing

I have a unsorted array containing only 0s and 1s. What is the best way to find the position of the first 1 in the array using n processor cores?

Comment: what is your question? How many steps are needed to calculate this with 'n' processors ? or what is the position of the first '1' ? If it is former, you  just have a window of 'n' and move it along the array. Maximum number of steps would be m/n where m is the size of array and n is the number of processors. If it is latter, do multi-threading ( Java / Python should have good examples ).

Comment: @SomeDude: presumably a theoretical question in parallel processing, with unlimited resources.

Answer (score 0):

Let every processor test a value and return its own index for a 1 and n for a 0.

Next every other processor returns the minimum of the value it returned and that its right neighbor returned.

Then every fourth processor and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the length of the array in advance, call this length k. Split the array into n parts having indices [0, k/n], [k/n+1, 2*k/n], ..., [(n-1)k/n+1, k). Create a static variable to store the index of the smallest part, and initialize it to `INT_MAX` (or equivalent). Assign one processor core (or thread) to sequentially go through the indices in each part, checking the index where the first 1 is found against the value of the static variable, and writing the new index if it is smaller (and returning). Mutexes/semaphores would need to be used to control reading/writing for the static variable. Use `thread_join` (or equivalent) to synchronize the completion of this operation for each thread, then print (or return) the index from the main thread.